# How to properly set up material-ui with electron-react-boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, electron, material-ui, electron-react-boilerplate

I'm having issues with material-ui (v4.9.5) library running with electron-react-boilerplate.
To reproduce:

1. follow the [installation tutorial](https://electron-react-boilerplate.js.org/docs/installation)
2. `yarn add @material-ui/core`
3. add some widgets from the library:

```
diff --git a/app/components/Home.tsx b/app/components/Home.tsx
index 20748ab..f4f9a21 100644
--- a/app/components/Home.tsx
+++ b/app/components/Home.tsx
@@ -1,11 +1,13 @@
 import React from 'react';
 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
+import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';
 import routes from '../constants/routes.json';
 import styles from './Home.css';

 export default function Home() {
   return (
     <div className={styles.container} data-tid="container">
+      <Button>Hello</Button>
       <h2>Home</h2>
       <Link to={routes.COUNTER}>to Counter</Link>
     </div>
```

Now everything works great when you run `yarn dev`. However, `yarn start` produces:

```
init.ts:204 Unable to load preload script: /home/vasniktel/boiler-test/app/dist/renderer.prod.js
(anonymous) @ init.ts:204
init.ts:205 TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'ontouchstart' in null
    at Module../app/index.tsx (/home/vasniktel/boiler-test/app/dist/renderer.prod.js:2)
    at n (/home/vasniktel/boiler-test/app/dist/renderer.prod.js:2)
    at module.exports../app/app.global.css (/home/vasniktel/boiler-test/app/dist/renderer.prod.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vasniktel/boiler-test/app/dist/renderer.prod.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vasniktel/boiler-test/app/dist/renderer.prod.js:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:735)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648)
    at Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:717)
(anonymous) @ init.ts:205
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I have this same exact problem but with a different package, also stuck on this currently!

Comment: I've added an issue on github https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate/issues/2395

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that removal of these lines from the `main.dev.ts` file solves the problem:

```
@@ -58,14 +58,9 @@ const createWindow = async () => {
     show: false,
     width: 1024,
     height: 728,
-    webPreferences:
-      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.E2E_BUILD === 'true'
-        ? {
-            nodeIntegration: true
-          }
-        : {
-            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/renderer.prod.js')
-          }
+    webPreferences: {
+      nodeIntegration: true
+    }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks it works now. But I'm wondering what does it do not to have renderer.prod.js for production builds ?